# Return employee time zone from AzureAD into Excel as non-admin user

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, power-query, time-zone, azure-activedirectory

**How do I retrieve a user's home base time zone as a UTC offset through a query, accounting for current DST settings?**

I'm a regular non-admin user. I use Power Query* to retrieve our employee list from AzureAD into Excel and do stuff.

**This sort of thing:*
[image]
Power Query is not required - it's just what I figured out. But the end result must be in Excel.

**Why?** Our company is global. For many reasons, especially Excel-based scheduling formulas, I need to know their UTC offset. (I don't work in GMT. It would be *nice* to know their time zone *name*, but I still need to know their time zone for the math.)

**Which time zone?** Home location. Current TZ is too variable.

**What about Daylight Savings offset?** For "Bob's" sake, can we destroy DST? Until we do, yeah, I need to know the net difference from UTC. (Uhh... what? I'm based in Eastern Time. DST applies over the summer. My official offset is UTC-5, but because of DST, my current offset is UTC-4.) I *do not* want to have to track everyone's DST date rules. Some nice person at Microsoft already did this; I want to benefit from their trauma.

*For this reason, I know the query results will always be slightly wrong around DST change periods. In a perfect world, the results would contain the UTC offset and the dates at which DST starts/stops for their region and I would figure out the math to know what the time differences will be on the date of the meeting. (Holy frack DST... just go away.)*

**Why not just use Excel's Geography Data Type against their city/country?** Completely insufficient. It fails for many reasons:

1. The city must be major enough to have time zone entries in whatever mysterious online data source Excel gets this info from.
2. One city can have multiple time zone results. (It's true.)
3. Excel 365 uses the #SPILL approach to return them as an array, which doesn't play well with formulas expecting one result. The employee, on the other hand, is in only one time zone.
4. Our data was entered by... humans. It's atrocious. Sometimes the city field is a city, sometimes it's a region, sometimes it's an apartment building name (!), sometimes it's empty. This is my problem to manage. But it's a real world reason why this approach won't work.

BTW - happy to use PowerShell.

I'm a little surprised this is so challenging.

Comment: So your attempting to convert UTC based on data manually inputted into an employee database?  I wasn't aware AzureAD would store that type of information.  FYI: Daylight Savings Time for EST would be EDT.  I have to ask, if you are dealing with multiple regions across dozens of time zones, why perform the conversion at all?  There is a reason the military for examples only deals in Zulu time (another name for UCT) and uses a 24 hour notation.

Comment: I operate in Zulu but say "UTC" for a general audience. :-) I don't want to convert - just need to know when meetings can occur. It's unclear to me what stores the TZ/DST offset, but *something* does, since our HRIS and Slack display current time even when the user's offline. I was hoping AAD would store kind of TZ info, but will happily query any source I can get. >2 ppl global meetings are a real pain, and that's well over 80% of these meetings. If I could get the UTC offset + DST status, then I can calculate people offset and sensible meeting times. Thanks, and hope that made some sense!

Comment: Oh yes - the set of TZ names and their DST variations are just bonkers. (I'm in Eastern, currently EDT, but I only ever see people say "I'm in EST." Drives me nuts.) I typically rely on https://timeanddate.com for all this stuff, but it's not practical at any scale beyond a single use. I need to personally know the city of the user, etc. I figure all that stuff should be present somewhere; I'm just hoping that somewhere is AAD.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only place AzureAD stores time zone "automatically" is as part of that user's mailbox settings, which the user sets manually using an Outlook client. Requesting this information from AzureAD requires specific permissions - at least `MailboxSettings.Read`

This information can be imported using the MS Graph API in plenty of different ways. Here's a powershell request for a specific user's time zone, using the `Microsoft.Graph.Authentication` module:

```sh
# Getting the time zone for a specific user 
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes MailboxSettings.Read
$userID = username@domain.com
$UserTZ = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method GET -ContentType "application\json" -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$userID/mailboxSettings/TimeZone"

# TZ stored as string in Windows format by default, like 'Eastern Standard Time'
# to convert the time zone text to UTC offset:
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($UserTZ.value)

# outputs:
Id                         : Eastern Standard Time
DisplayName                : (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
StandardName               : Eastern Standard Time
DaylightName               : Eastern Daylight Time
BaseUtcOffset              : -05:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : True
```

I'm not familiar enough with Excel to do the same steps there, but [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-office-365-data-in-excel-using-ms-graph-api/) describes how to import ms graph data using an OData feed data connection.

---

A different way to get the same data is by connecting to Exchange and getting the time zone setting from the mailboxes there. This method is powershell-only, and requires that

- You're a member of at least the `View-Only Organization Management` role group in Exchange
- Your O365 user has remote powershell enabled (true by default)
- You install the [ExchangeOnlineManagement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-and-maintain-the-exo-v2-module) module

Then it's just `Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration` for each user like so:

```sh
Connect-ExchangeOnline

Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration -Identity john@contoso.com | 
  Select Identity,TimeZone

# outputs
Identity     TimeZone             
--------     --------             
John Smith   Eastern Standard Time
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I've learned a bit of PowerShell and should be able to pull the user list and include the time zone call. I won't be quick to confirm the answer (n00b here!) but will give it a shot. An export to CSV is every bit as good as a pull directly into Excel!

Comment: Unable to connect. I've made two simple changes: 1. Enquoted US "&" Canada and 2. enquoted the value of "username@domain.com". Failures now seem to be about Connect-MgGraph timing out after 120 seconds and of course everything fails after that. Three different approaches to Connect-MgGraph all fail: 1. Connect-MgGraph -Scopes MailboxSettings.Read, 2. Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All" (your original), and 3. Connect-MgGraph -TenantId 397xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. (Wish we could put line breaks in comments.) I'm 100% new to MgGraph, so there's a lot of experimentation going on. :-)

Comment: The default behavior of `Connect-MgGraph` is to open an O365 login prompt window (or launch your default browser at https://login.microsoftonline.com/ ). Unless there's some weird issue, you should at least see the login. I'll add another simpler option since you mention you probably don't need to get these very often

Comment: @Neman I've added steps using a different module, which may work better for you, though it does require access to exchange

Comment: Amazing @Cpt.Whale! We're SO CLOSE - the EXO method works for my UPN, but nobody else's so far. `(The specified mailbox Identity:"bob.loblaw@company.com" doesn't exist.)` I suspect that's because of the prereq you mentioned of being in at least View-Only Organization Management. According to https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_UsersAndTenants/UserProfileMenuBlade/~/AdministrativeRole/userId/MyGUID, I have no assigned roles. Which means it's now in my court to make a case to my IT department for the permission, as I'm just a user. Once it works, I can make a lookup table for TZ names.

Comment: Also: Yes, I did get an O365 login prompt as you identified for the `Connect-MgGraph` option. But the timeouts, etc. mentioned all happen after that. I re-ran the `Connect-MgGraph` option a moment ago and got more verification prompts that require me to be an admin/`MailboxSettings.Read` as you pointed out. I think since the EXO method does retrieve an answer and the permissions are my problem, I'm happy to consider this solved, even though it doesn't work for me as a non-admin user. I'm starting to suspect non-admin users can't get this type of information.

Comment: @Neman your suspicion is correct that being unable to see other's settings is a permissions issue. This property is treated kind of strangely, and is not as public as I thought at first. At least it doesn't require access to mailboxes or anything

Comment: Got it working! IT made an Azure app for me with MailboxSettings.Read permissions as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/app-only?view=graph-powershell-1.0&tabs=azure-portal. The app logs in, not me, and can't access other people's mailboxes. (Note the app will be missing the Redirect URI until you discover what that is - it's displayed at run time when the login attempt fails.) I've edited your Graph-based answer to include an example of the syntax to log in as an app using its Client ID. Now I just have to figure out how to get an employee list and loop through it.